# what will be the resistor to find the time constant?

Tags: capacitor, inductor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCA5lu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What resistance should I use to find the time constant? is it 30 ohm or 1130 ohm?
what if the capacitor is an inductor will I be using the same value for the resistor to find the time constant?

Comment: Which point's voltage are you measuring?
time constant = R*C = L/R

Comment: "Yes" to your second and third questions.

Comment: If you were to swap the position of any two components (say replace R1 with R3 and vice versa) would it make any difference to the (charging) current?

Comment: Channel 1 of the oscilloscope is connected before the capacitor, and channel 2 is connected after the capacitor.

Comment: @JImDearden I am not sure, no I don't think the current will change

Comment: @SpehroPefhany which of those 30 oh or 1130ohm?

Comment: @eLg  so if you added all the resistors together and substituted just one resistor for all three would it make a difference to the charging current?

Comment: no, it will not make any difference in the current (thevenin?)

Comment: @eLg If the current is the same as with one resistor, then I think you know the answer.

Comment: The important part is not the resist*or*, it's the resist*ance*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply understand the circuit you can locate a proper ground point to use as a reference for calculations and transformations of the circuit. In case of the oscilloscope, you can take one of it's connectors as the ground and split the circuit to make it easier to *digest*.

Given the oscillograph connections, you can transform the circuit to look like this. Does it make more sense this way?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3jb0R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Try simulating it and measure the time constant from the graph, then calculate what it should be. The time constant tau is the time which it takes for the voltage to rise or fall to $$V_{initial}+(1-\frac{1}{e})\times(V_{final}-V_{initial})$$ where \$V_{initial}\$ is the stable voltage before the switching and \$V_{final}\$ is the voltage after the switching. So if before the switch it was 0 and after the switch it is 1, the time constant will be the time it took for the voltage to rise to ~0.63V.
- Try replacing the capacitor with an inductive coil and see what happens in the time simulations to answer your last question thoroughly. Remember that$$ \tau = R \times C= \frac{L}{R}$$

Comment: how to get the time constant from the graph?

Comment: i thought I need to multiply v0 to 0.368? the locate it from the graph and find the time where it was located, and that time is the tau?

Comment: where to get Vinitial and Vfinal?sorry for the questions. I am new electric circuits.

Comment: I mixed things up a bit. The formula should be $$V_{initial}+\frac{1}{e}*(V_{final}-V_{initial})$$
Where V_initial is the stable starting voltage before the change to another voltage and V_final the stable final voltage after the change.

Comment: i got 426ms as tau

Comment: You have to deduct the starting time of the transition to get the true tau.

Comment: I am not getting it, please help

Comment: Right now on the simulation at 40ms it switches on. Check how much time from the 40 ms point it takes to reach $$-1+0.63*(1-(-1))$$ volts. That's the time constant tau.

Comment: if I use the formula, i will get 1.13*10^-3 s

Comment: That is what you should be seeing on the graph too. It starts rising at 40ms and at 41.13 it reaches ~0.264V volts. The 1/e in the previous formula should've been (1-1/e), sorry, I'm making silly mistakes tonight.

Comment: can I ask you one more question?

Comment: Sure, just make it fast. :)

Comment: how will I find the current of the capacitor or the voltage of the inductor based on this problem?

Comment: someone said that i need to use Ic(max)=Vc/30, and Vl(max)= Il(max)(30)...

Comment: $$I_{C}(t)=C*\frac{dU(t)}{dt}$$
$$U_{L}(t)=L*\frac{dI(t)}{dt}$$
If you want just the maximum values, then maximum current is when capacitor is not charged, so effectively a short, then $$I_{C max} = \frac{V_{Source}}{1130}$$ for the inductor, in the first moment after switching it's as if it was an open circuit where it is, so U_L would be V_Source

Comment: what how to get the derivative of voltage, and current if there are no formulas? I know how to do derivatives...

Comment: I can't really teach you calculus here. :) You should read some textbooks about this. I recommend *The Art of Electronics*, it's got good explanations of this stuff and you'll see how to get the formulas for current and voltage.

Comment: Vsource? will that be the Vpk-pk or Vpk? I used a function generator and make the frequency to 1kHz

Comment: The maximum voltage given by the signal source. It's the amplitude of the signal. I guess you could call it V peak (Vpk).

Comment: if I have a 6v pk-pk...My Vsource will be 3V?

Comment: Should be. But with 1kHz the voltage doesn't have enough time to settle. So the maximum voltage on the capacitor will probably be less and therefore a smaller max current

Answer (score 0):

The time constant is determined by the equivalent resistance in series with the capacitor.  In this case, it is the sum of the 3 resistors (1130 ohms) since they are all connected in series.

Comment: But the 30ohm is not in series with the other 2 resistors?

Comment: @eLg: All 4 components are in series.